# How to HTTP POST a Blob to a different domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, blob, same-origin-policy

I have some `Blob()` object. I want to upload somewhere else (a website that handle user upload through forms).

I can put them in a **FormData** and send them through an **XMLHttpRequest** object, but then I can't read the ajax response, because I'm blocked by the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) of the ajax call.

How can I get around this? Is there some way to do a regular upload without using ajax? Is there a way to deal with that "same origin policy" that will work on recent versions of Chrome and Firefox?

edit: Not sure this is a duplicate: **I don't control the server being posted**, so I'm not OK with just *"setting the same origin policy on both domains"*.

Comment: You can't read content blocked by SOP regardless of whether it's XMLHttpRequest, POST or GET, FormData&Blob or normal parameters…

Answer (score 0):

In most cases when someone is trying to use AJAX across domains but is blocked by the same origin policy, it is recommended to AJAX to your own PHP page, and then use cURL to send that data to a different site.

http://curl.haxx.se/

Comment: I don't really get the concept here. You mean that i should send the ajax request to MY server, then from my server perform a classic HTTP POST ?

Comment: Essentially that's the only way I've ever seen to do it.  cURL is a PHP library that lets you send data to other domains, so basically you should send the AJAX request to your own PHP page on your own server, and then use cURL in your PHP page to send your data along to whatever other domain you're trying to access.